# How to insert data into database with a auto_increment key in go

Tags: mysql, go

I have a SQL database with a table named blogpost, it has a column id set to auto_increment now I have to insert a value into the database, I used the following code:

```
 _, err := db.Exec("Insert  into blogpost (id, title, description, author) values(?,?,?)", newBlog.Title, newBlog.Description, newBlog.Author)
```

but I get a following error:

```
Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Column count doesn't match value count at row 1` is displayed because you've defined 3 parameters and not 4.

You defined `id, title, description and author` which is a total of 4 columns. Whereas where you provide your values, you only have a total of 3 `values(?,?,?)`.

If you have the `id` already set as `auto_icnrement`, you don't need to do anything in your insert method, just take it out like so:

```
 _, err := db.Exec("Insert  into blogpost (title, description, author) values(?,?,?)", newBlog.Title, newBlog.Description, newBlog.Author)
```

Answer (score 0):

try to remove **id** from fields list